# Error launching Android emulator in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

A few days ago worked fine but after Visual Studio updated I get this error:

> 1>Starting implementation en pixel_5_-*api_30...
> 1>Iniciando el emulador pixel_5*-*api_30 ...
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -netfast -accel on -avd pixel_5*-*api_30 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_5*-*api_30
> 1>**Can't start emulator** pixel_5*-_api_30.

Also there is a disconnection between Visual Studio and the Android Devices Administrator because when I create a new device I have to reopen Visual to refresh changes, which didn't happen before the updating.
I also reinstall VS, remove all Android and SDK folders, remove userdata-qemu.img file, nothing worked.

Note: The emulator throws this message: Device error: Could not get emulator name after starting AVD pixel_5_-_api_30

**UPDATE:**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator>emulator.exe -avd pixel_5_-_api_30 -wipe-data
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.1.4.0 (build_id 7920983) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
ERROR   | Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in' C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8556, security: Local INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_19240.ini Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object Failed to create voice` adc'
WARNING | Not saving state: RAM not mapped as shared

**UPDATE 2**: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator>emulator.exe -avd pixel_5_-_api_30 -wipe-data
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.1.4.0 (build_id 7920983) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
ERROR   | Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\Jose\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_8576.ini
WARNING | Not saving state: RAM not mapped as shared

Comment: 1) VS Tools / Android SDK Manager / Tab "Tools" - does "Android Emulator" need an Update? 2) Are you saying that error message happens when "Start" the emulator from "Android Device Manager"? Or when you launch your project from VS? Or both?

Comment: It is all updated and the error occur when I launch the project from VS after start the emulator.

Comment: check the sdk version,  try reinstall/install version to match the emulator

Comment: Android SDK Platform-Tools is 31.0.3 and Android Emulator is 31.1.4 from VS/Tools/Android/Android SDK Manager. It is not a match 100% but the tools says it is all updated. Now when I launch the emulator I get 'Resetting for cold boot: emulation engine failed', it dissapears in a blink but I was able to screenshot.

Comment: If I run C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices in command line I get emulator-5554   offline and restoring I get the message added to the first post because the comment is too long to be written in here

Comment: I fixed the 'sound' issue but i still get the message tittled 'UPDATED 2' from the first post.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the steps to get the error, I will create a new clear post and I will delete this one, sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your help.